# Optimizing multiple repetitive if statements working with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, conditional-statements

I am working on a small program to play tictactoe with the computer, however when it comes to checking who is the winner, I made a function that checks the array that represents the board for any 'X's or 'O's that go across the board vertically, horizontally and across.  Just by looking at the code I can see a lot of repetition and I was just looking on suggestions on how to optimize it.

I have tried combining the if statements for 'X's and 'O's but I can't combine them as I need each one to print a different message to the output.  The first if statement checks each row for all X values, the second checks vertically, and the third and fourth check values across the board.

```
for i in range(3):
    if myDict[0][i] == 'X' and myDict[1][i] == 'X' and myDict[2][i] == 'X':
        print('You Lose!!!')
        DisplayBoard(myDict)
        return False
    elif myDict[i][0] == 'X' and myDict[i][1] == 'X' and myDict[i][2] == 'X':
        print('You Lose!!!')
        DisplayBoard(myDict)
        return False
if myDict[0][0] == 'X' and myDict[1][1] == 'X' and myDict[2][2] == 'X':
    print('You Lose!!!')
    DisplayBoard(myDict)
    return False
elif myDict[0][2] == 'X' and myDict[1][1] == 'X' and myDict[2][0] == 'X':
    print('You Lose!!!')
    DisplayBoard(myDict)
    return False

for i in range(3):
    if myDict[0][i] == 'O' and myDict[1][i] == 'O' and myDict[2][i] == 'O':
        print('You Win!!!')
        DisplayBoard(myDict)
        return False
    elif myDict[i][0] == 'O' and myDict[i][1] == 'O' and myDict[i][2] == 'O':
        print('You Win!!!')
        DisplayBoard(myDict)
        return False
if myDict[0][0] == 'O' and myDict[1][1] == 'O' and myDict[2][2] == 'O':
    print('You Win!!!')
    DisplayBoard(myDict)
    return False
elif myDict[0][2] == 'O' and myDict[1][1] == 'O' and myDict[2][0] == 'O':
    print('You Win!!!')
    DisplayBoard(myDict)
    return False
return True
```

The program works, just looking to find ways to optimize the code.

Answer (score 0):

`myDict[0][i] == 'X' and myDict[1][i] == 'X' and myDict[2][i] == 'X'`

can be replaced with

`all(myDict[j][i]=='X' for j in range(3))`

---

The pair of `if`/`elif` statements can be combined with an `or`.

---

You can also replace the duplicated code by writing a function that takes the player (`'X'` or `'O'`) as an argument. Just call the function once for each player.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an indirection to identify the indexes that you want to combine and looping through the list of groups to form a generalized condition.

For example:

```
axes = [ [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)], [(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)], [(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)],
         [(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)], [(0,1),(1,1),(2,1)], [(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)],
         [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)], [(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)] ]

winner = "O"
for axis in axes:
    p = "".join(myDict[r][c] for r,c in axis)
    if p = "OOO": winner = "O"
    if p = "XXX": winner = "X" 
if winner == "O": print("You Win!!!")
if winner == "X": print("You Lose!!!")
```